# Existe alguma forma de acessar um cookie de um domínio diferente?

Tags: aplicação-web, cookies

Existe alguma forma de eu acessar um cookie de um domínio diferente?

Por exemplo: tem um cookie no facebook.com.br e eu quero acessar dados do cookie dentro do meu site www.fulano.com.br .

Comment: Como assim de um dominio diferente? Os cookies guardam-se no computador do cliente.

Comment: @Sergio Tipo eu tenho meu site dominio "meusite.com.br" eu crio um cookie variável visitou aí eu tenho outro site meusite2.com.br que eu preciso buscar esse cookie do "meusite.com.br" se ele entrou naquele site... fiquei sabendo que cookie só pode ser acessado pelo mesmo dominio.

Comment: Só se você tiver controle sobre o site que quer obter o cookie, caso contrário não.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode ler os cookies de outro domínio isto é fato.

A única maneira que eu posso pensar é adicionar algum código para o segundo domínio que recebe os cookies para você e, em seguida, colocar isso em uma página no 1º de domínio, em um iframe.

Você, obviamente, precisa de acesso completo para ambos os domínios para ser capaz de fazer esse tipo de coisa.